# problems getting a new position vector3

Tags: unity, c#

could someone explain to me why i can't get a new position that is outside the update method.

if i set what's inside the void callposic to a Start I can't get any position, only if it's inside the update

what can you do, because I don't want to use them in the update board.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNzJ5GUYAOA&feature=youtu.be

```
public int index;
public Vector3[] posic;
void Start()
{
    prev.onClick.AddListener(() => void1(-1));
    next.onClick.AddListener(() => void1(1));
    index = 0;

}

void Update()
{
    callposic();
}

void callposic()
{
    transform.localPosition = posic[index];
}

void void1(int value) { index = index + value; }
```

}

Comment: the way i did it does not require the call, i get it directly using the values that are within the parameters and switch to an onclick and the update does the rest.

this is the script.

Comment: Can you clarify, what specifically goes wrong if you try to read the position in Start? What value do you get, and how does that compare with the value you expect?

Comment: that's the problem if I leave it at Start, it doesn't read any position. because, as you can see, it doesn’t move at speed, it’s just locomotion, so there’s no reason I’d leave it in the update, so I came to ask for help because certain things I don’t know how to do

Comment: "as you can see" No, I cannot see that. That's why I"m asking you to explain. What do you expect your game to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: there be added a video

Comment: Remember, we know nothing about your project except what you tell us. In the video I see a square snapping to different positions on a track when you click buttons. Is that your desired behaviour? If so, what is the problem? If that is not your desired behaviour, what should happen instead?

Comment: It might be easier to find your problem if you don't post the code that works (but doesn't do what you want) and instead post the code that doesn't work. The video doesn't give me any clues about what you want either.

Comment: the script that is in the post and the same in the video does not contain any errors, I just wanted to remove it from the update and leave it at the beginning, but if I do, the script will stop working.
for example, I call callposic () in the update; if I replace it with start, it doesn't find the positions in vector3

Comment: You know Start only runs once, not every time you press the button, right? Did you mean to put this position change in your button click handler method instead?

Comment: that's exactly it, is there any way to adapt it using the same method as my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like what you want to do is this:

```
public int currentPositionIndex;
public Vector3[] positions;

public Button previousButton;
public Button nextButton;

void Start() {
    prev.onClick.AddListener(IncreaseIndex);
    next.onClick.AddListener(DecreaseIndex);
    // We don't strictly need to initialize currentPositionIndex here;
    // it'll use its serialized value.
}

// I named these methods for clarity.
void IncreaseIndex() { ChangeIndex(1); }
void DecreaseIndex() { ChangeIndex(-1); }

void ChangeIndex(int delta) { 
    // Let's clamp this to ensure we don't go outside our array bounds.
    currentPositionIndex = Mathf.Clamp(currentPositionIndex + delta, 0, positions.Length -1);

    // Our index has (potentially) changed! Update our position to match.
    transform.localPosition = positions[currentPositionIndex];
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering my questions, i had already solved it. I'll leave my method below

Answer (score 0):

```
void callposic()
{
    transform.localPosition = posic[index];

   if (index == posic.Length - 1)
   next.gameObject.SetActive(false);
   else
   next.gameObject.SetActive(true);

   if (index == 0)
   prev.gameObject.SetActive(false);
   else
   prev.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

void void1(int value) 
{ 
   index = index + value; 
    callposic();
}
```